# Extract only jpg files from a .tar.gz file using python

Tags: python, path, extract, unzip, tarfile

**Problem Summary:**
In one of my folder I have .tar.gz file and I need to extract all the images (.jpg & .png) from it. But I have to use the .tar.gz extension (using path to directory) to extract it and not by using the usual way of giving the input file_name to extract it. I need this in one of the part of GUI (Tkinter) for the image classification project.

**Code I'm trying:**

```py
import os
import tarfile

def extractfile():
    os.chdir('GUI_Tkinter/PMC_downloads')
    with tarfile.open(os.path.join(os.environ['GUI_Tkinter/PMC_downloads'], f'Backup_{self.batch_id}.tar.gz'), "r:gz") as so:
        so.extractall(path=os.environ['GUI_Tkinter/PMC_downloads'])
```

The code is not giving any error but it's not working. Please suggest me how to do the same by any other way by specifying the .tar.gz file extension to extract it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generic/dynamic way to extract one or more .tar.gz or zip file present in a folder without specifying the file name. This is executed by using the extension and the path (location) of the file. You can extract any type of file (.pdf, .nxml, .xml, .gif, etc.) you want from the .tar.gz/zip/compressed file just by mentioning the extension of the required file as the member name in this code. As, I needed all the images from that .tar.gz file to be extracted in one folder. So, in the code below I have specified the extensions .jpg and .png and extracted all the images in the same directory under a folder named "Extracted_Images". If you want, you can also change the directory where the files needed to be extracted by providing the path parameter.

For example "C:/Users/dell/project/histo_images" instead of "Extracted_Images".

```py
import tarfile
import os
import glob

path = glob.glob("*.tar.gz")

for file in path:
    t = tarfile.open(file, 'r')
    for member in t.getmembers():
        if ".jpg" in member.name:
            t.extract(member, "Extracted_Images")
        elif ".png" in member.name:
            t.extract(member, "Extracted_Images")
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use this code.

```
import tarfile
import os

t = tarfile.open('example.tar.gz', 'r')
for member in t.getmembers():
    if ".jpg" in member.name:
        t.extract(member, "outdir")

print(os.listdir('outdir'))
```

Hope to be helpful for you. Thanks.

Comment: In this solution you are specifying the name of the file which need to be extracted but I need to extract it by specifying only .tar.gz extension. Thanks - @lionking-123.

Comment: How to use .endswith here ?

Comment: Hello, it doesn't work? It is working well in my side.

Comment: Hello, why don't you check my code? I think above code is the same with me. And I think I have answered faster than above. So, I think I can get voteup for this answer.